# Faster way to query pandas dataframe for a value based on values in other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/tsaustin/us-historical-stock-prices-with-earnings-data) from Kaggle which contains about 4.6 million rows of data after some filtering
[image]

I want to query this dataframe for the `close_adjusted` value where the `symbol` and `date` is equal to some value. This is my implementation so far

```
def price_diff(date_one, date_two, symbol):

    data = df.loc[df['symbol'] == symbol]
    date_one_data = data.loc[data['date'] == date_one]
    date_two_data = data.loc[data['date'] == date_two]

    # Only if data from both dates exist
    if (len(date_one_data) > 0 and len(date_two_data) > 0):
        close_price_one = date_one_data.squeeze()['close_adjusted']
        close_price_two = date_two_data.squeeze()['close_adjusted']
        return close_price_one - close_price_two

    return dummy
```

This code took about 523 ms to run: `523 ms ± 1.54 ms per loop`

Is there a faster way I can achieve what I want? Right now applying the above function to a dataset with 25000 rows of dates and symbols take more than an hour on a Kaggle notebook.

Thanks!

Comment: try to set symbol/date as the index and then filter.

Comment: Setting date/symbol as index doesn't seem to speed it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some profiling, I found that the majority of your compute time is spent filtering out the `symbol`. Instead of using the dataframe to do your filtering, you can increase the speed by accessing the underlying numpy array that powers the dataframe since it is much faster. The array can be accessed using the `ravel()` function.

```
def price_diff_ME(date_one, date_two, symbol):

    #data = df.loc[df['symbol'] == symbol]
    data = df[df["symbol"].ravel() == symbol]

    date_one_data = data.loc[data['date'] == date_one]
    date_two_data = data.loc[data['date'] == date_two]

    # Only if data from both dates exist
    if (len(date_one_data) > 0 and len(date_two_data) > 0):
        close_price_one = date_one_data.squeeze()['close_adjusted']
        close_price_two = date_two_data.squeeze()['close_adjusted']
        return close_price_one - close_price_two

    return False
```

After using `ravel()` to get a numpy array, I simply ran the same filter as before to produce a binary mask. I then apply the mask to the dataframe to reproduce the same filter that you had earlier.

Just by changing that one line, I was able to see a 70% increase in speed. You can use the same method to filter out the other dates too if you would like.

Comment: This did improve the speed. On the same notebook it now takes: `171 ms ± 721 µs per loop`.  Thanks!